# Angular/NGXS sample code - cannot get reference of the parameter input

Tags: angular, angular6, rxjs6, ngxs

I'm trying to implement the login as mentioned here.

https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/recipes/authentication

```
  @Action(Login)
  login({ patchState }: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, { payload: { username } }: Login) {
    return this.authService.login(payload).pipe(tap((result: { token: string }) => {
      patchState({ token, username });
    }))
  }
```

But I'm unable to get the reference of 'payload' as shown in the sample, instead I get the following error. Any help appreciated ! I also wanted to know what '{ payload: { username } }' would mean in the input parameters of the function.

[image]

Comment: Aby, did my answer shed light on your issue? I've explained the [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), identified the error, and showed the solution. Did you get past this issue?

Comment: Yes, absolutely Rafael. Thanks for your time !! keep up the good job.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad to hear that. The fix was merged in [#653](https://github.com/ngxs/store/pull/653)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error in the documentation.

Look here:

```
export class Login {
  static readonly type = '[Auth] Login';
  constructor(public payload: { username: string, password: string }) {}
}
```

and here:

```
login({ patchState }: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, { payload: { username } }: Login) {
```

This is a destructure mistake and needs to be:

```
@Action(Login)
login({ patchState }: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, { payload }: Login) {
  return this.authService.login(payload).pipe(tap((result: { token: string }) => {
    patchState({ token, username: payload.username });
  }))
}
```

This destructures Login's `payload` and then reference `username` via `payload.username`.

Credentials are sent upstream and a token is returned downstream. The AuthStateModel is patched via the StateContext.

[Git Blame authentication.md](https://github.com/ngxs/store/blame/ec7aec21d55808a0350dc32c3f1c159246cb9f4e/docs/recipes/authentication.md#L41)

What Is Destructuring?

`{ payload: { username } }` is [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
. In the context of a function parameter, it means, "in this object, I am interested in these properties." Looking at `login()`, it means, "I am only interested in `username` (which is wrong as state above).

I hope this helps!

**UPDATE:**

This fix has been merged in [#653](https://github.com/ngxs/store/pull/653).

Just to clarify:

```js
let a = { payload: { username: { first: 'rafael', last: 'cepeda' } } };
let { payload: { username } } = a;//unwraps payload.username
console.log(username);//works
console.log(payload);//error
```

Fix:

```js
let a = { payload: { username: { first: 'rafael', last: 'cepeda' } } };
let { payload } = a;//unwraps payload
console.log(payload.username);//works
console.log(payload);//works
```